# Uniform way to access %ProgramFiles(x86)% in Vista 32 bit and Win 7 64 bit

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, x86

I am developing a java application and deploy it using batch file. At work, I use Vista 32 bit and at home I use win 7 64 bit. The batch file calls java.exe to do some tasks

Due to some issue with Netbeans, I am forced to do my development on 32 bit java (both at home and at work), so at home I have a 32 bit jdk installed in %ProgramFiles(x86)% on which I do my development and also the 64 bit jre in %ProgramFiles% (which is used for other stuff)

Is there any uniform way to access the 32 bit folder on both work and home computers, so I don't have to have two copies of batch files (the home one calling java.exe in %ProgramFiles(x86)% and the office one calling default java.exe (in %ProgramFiles%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do something like this:

```
set programfiles32=%programfiles(x86)%
if "%programfiles32%"=="" set programfiles32=%programfiles%

copy foo.dll "%programfiles32%"
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Vista, so I used the following: `IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (set ProgramFiles32="%ProgramFiles(x86)%") ELSE (set ProgramFiles32=%ProgramFiles%)`

Comment: @Jus12: we have developers on XP, Vista and Windows 7 and we haven't had any problems with this. (But only the Windows 7 machines are 64-bit I think.) What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

This may surprise you, but when you execute `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` without specifying a path, it executes the copy in `C:\Windows\system32`.  These copies are actually redirectors that read registry keys to determine the latest Java version installed.  However, it can be overridden via the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

You can set environment variables per-user or system-wide in Windows under Control Panel, System, Advanced tab, Environment Variables button... or at least that's where it's located on my XP work machine.  I seem to recall it's still in the same location on my Win7 home machine.

Edit: I forgot to mention this, but `JAVA_HOME`'s value should be the path to the main directory for your JVM/JDK.  For my 32-bit XP dev box, that's `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24` because my dev tools need access to executables from the JDK.

Comment: hmm so if the batch file sets `%JAVA_HOME%`, then it should be fine.

Comment: Another interesting feature of Windows that I discovered `cd %ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.6.0*` changes to the correct JDK directory (in my case `jdk1.6.0_24`). This is useful since I have two different versions of jdk running at work and home.

Comment: @Jus12: Where `%ProgramFiles%` goes on a 64-bit Windows [depends entirely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) on if the process requesting it is 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: @Jus12 There are 2 cmd.exe files. The one in system32 is 64 bit and the one in sysWOW64 is 32 bit. By default when you type an external command without specific path, the one in system32 will be called